# .net core using visual studio code

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, rest, .net-core

I am now creating a rest api in **.net core** using **visual studio code**,
is there anyone here knows how to add a app.config or web.config in this setup? or there any equivalent file here in visual studio code.

Comment: This seems a good starting point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-vsc?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: There isn't an `app.config`, or a `web.config`. I recommend reading Microsoft's docs on [configuration in .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration).

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code as IDE

Answer (score -1):

You should use .NET Core Configuration API in the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` package. It's more flexible than .NET Framework `app` or `web.config`, for example it allows you to use multiple configuration sources in different formats (JSON and XML included).

Here's a link to Microsoft docs about .NET Core Configuration:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20529404)

Comment: Sorry for that and thanks for pointing that out to me. Is this edited version better?

Comment: I already fixed it. Thanks anyway